# Changing a Hash in ruby using an enumerator

Tags: ruby, hash, dictionary, block

Here is my example program:

```
what = {:banana=>:fruit, :pear=>:fruit, :sandal=>:fruit, :panda=>:fruit, :apple=>:fruit}

what.map do |w| 
    p "is this right?"
    awesome_print w
    fix = gets
    fix.chop!
    if (fix == "N")
        p "Tell me what it should be"
        correction = gets
        w[1] = correction.chop!.to_sym
    end
    p w
end
```

I run it, and I get this (my input included):

```
"is this right?"
[
    [0] :banana,
    [1] :fruit
]
Y
[:banana, :fruit]
"is this right?"
[
    [0] :pear,
    [1] :fruit
]
Y
[:pear, :fruit]
"is this right?"
[
    [0] :sandal,
    [1] :fruit
]
N
"Tell me what it should be"
footwear
[:sandal, :footwear]
"is this right?"
[
    [0] :panda,
    [1] :fruit
]
N
"Tell me what it should be"
animal
[:panda, :animal]
"is this right?"
[
    [0] :apple,
    [1] :fruit
]
Y
[:apple, :fruit]
=> [[:banana, :fruit], [:pear, :fruit], [:sandal, :footwear], [:panda, :animal], [:apple, :fruit]]
>> what
=> {:banana=>:fruit, :pear=>:fruit, :sandal=>:fruit, :panda=>:fruit, :apple=>:fruit}
```

My question is how can I change the Hash? irb tells me when I run the program that each enumerated element is processed, but the results aren't saved in my hash `what`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to mutate the hash in place (as you seem to want), simply do this:

```
my_hash.each do |key,value|       # map would work just as well, but not needed
  my_hash[key] = some_new_value    
end
```

If you want to create a new hash, without changing the original:

```
new_hash = Hash[ my_hash.map do |key,value|
  [ key, new_value ]
end ]
```

The way this works is that [`Enumerable#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) returns an array (in this case an array of two-element key/value pairs), and [`Hash.[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) can turn `[ [a,b], [c,d] ]` into `{ a=>b, c=>d }`.

What you were doing—`hash.map{ … }`—was mapping each key/value pair to a new value and creating an array…and then doing nothing with that array. While there *is* `Array#map!` which will destructively mutate an array in place, there is no equivalent `Hash#map!` to destructively mutate a hash in a single step.

---

Note also that if you want to destructively mutate a Hash—or any other object that references other mutable objects—in place you can just destructively mutate those objects during normal iteration:

```
# A simple hash with mutable strings as values (not symbols)
h = { a:"zeroth", b:"first", c:"second", d:"third" }

# Mutate each string value
h.each.with_index{ |(char,str),index| str[0..-3] = index.to_s }

p h #=> {:a=>"0th", :b=>"1st", :c=>"2nd", :d=>"3rd"}
```

However, since you are using symbols for the values in your sample code—and since symbols are **not** mutable—this final note does not directly apply there.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
w[1] = correction.chop!.to_sym
```

Try assigning to the hash directly:

```
what[w[0]] = correction.chop!.to_sym
```

Ruby is creating that `w` array just to pass you the key and value. Assigning to that array isn't going to change your hash; it's only changing that temporary array.